# WhenEvent inside Ndsolve how to evaluate actions numerically every time the event happens

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, evaluation, pattern-matching

I need to force a whenevent action to be evaluated numerically all the times the event happens.
The fact is that I use very complicated matrices and I need to invert them so the system requires a lot of time to work. Is there a way to make whenevent work only with numerical values in order to go faster? 
I post a sort of toy model to represent what would I want to do:

```
Attributes[WhenEvent] = {};
ser[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]};
Aw = {{-1, 2}, {0, -4}};
fun := Inverse[{{x1[t]*x2[t]^2,  37}, {x1[t]*Cos[x2[t]], 2} }];
eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};

eqdyn = D[ser[t], t] == Aw.ser[t];
eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};

ev = WhenEvent[
  Mod[t, 1], {ser[t] ->  fun.ser[t], "RestartIntegration"}]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqinn, ev}, ser[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Now If I execute ev I obtain:

```
ev

(*WhenEvent[
 Mod[t, 1], {{x1[t], 
    x2[t]} -> {(2 x1[t])/(-37 Cos[x2[t]] x1[t] + 2 x1[t] x2[t]^2) - (
     37 x2[t])/(-37 Cos[x2[t]] x1[t] + 2 x1[t] x2[t]^2), -((
      Cos[x2[t]] x1[t]^2)/(-37 Cos[x2[t]] x1[t] + 
       2 x1[t] x2[t]^2)) + (
     x1[t] x2[t]^3)/(-37 Cos[x2[t]] x1[t] + 2 x1[t] x2[t]^2)}, 
  "RestartIntegration"}]*)
```

Just because it evaluates fun. In the real problem I can't do this way.
A solution is to use the pattern test _?NumericQ, but I ask if is there another way because the function arguments would be too much in too much functions so I wouldn't write them every time as function arguments

So my goal is to have:

```
ev

(*WhenEvent[
 Mod[t, 1], {{x1[t], 
    x2[t]} -> fun.ser[t]}, 
  "RestartIntegration"}]*)
```

I would want that every time event happens It substitutes symbolic values with numerical values and then go on with matrix inversion

Comment: Why do you need to invert the matrices? I suggest that all you want is to solve linear systems. You rarely need to actually invert a matrix which takes a lot of time as you noticed.

Comment: @Somos In the real task I need to implement an hybrid kalman filter, and for the update step I need to invert a matrix. Thanks for the advice I'll go deep with your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

For this system we can make numerical code, but we need to test it with a large system

```
Attributes[WhenEvent] = {};
ser[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]};
Aw = {{-1, 2}, {0, -4}};

func = Block[{x, y}, 
   With[{code = Inverse[{{x*y^2, 37}, {x*Cos[y], 2}}]}, 
    Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]]];
funQ[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := func[x, y];

eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};

eqdyn = D[ser[t], t] == Aw . ser[t];
eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};


ev = WhenEvent[
   Mod[t, 1], {ser[t] -> funQ[x1[t], x2[t]] . ser[t], 
    "RestartIntegration"}];


sol = NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqinn, ev}, ser[t], {t, 0, 4}];

Plot[sol, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I didn't know the use of compile. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it in my original code.

Comment: @PeaceEverybody In a case of singular matrix when `Inverse` and `LinearSolve` not working we can use `PseudoInverse` with this code.

Comment: If I understand this right, this code computes the inverse symbolically and then compiles the result, where the code of @PeaceEverybody just uses the symbolic inverse.  So the main difference is that this code compiles `func` -- is that right? (BTW, you can get rid of `funQ` if you use the `Compile` option `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, your are right  that  with  `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` we can avoid message from `Compile`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev in my original code I have all the variables time dependent, do you know if is there a way to force the numerical evaluation when the variable is function of x[t] and not x ?
For example I got something like A which is a 5X5 matrix full of time dependent variables and I want it is evaluated only when it is numeric inside the ndsolve in which the time dependent variables are calculated

Comment: @AlexTrounev Maybe I'm going off-topic but it's useful to my question. Is there a way to define a function oh the type f[x[t]] := 3 x[t] and make it works as usually do ?

Comment: @PeaceEverybody It depends on the system you try to solve. In numerical computation there is could be singular matrix (and this always happened). It is why mostly methods applicable for a toy system can be useless with a large system.  So we can't solve your problem in general.  But we can solve particular problem. Hence, better you show your real system.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `LinearSolve` instead of `Inverse`:

```
ser[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]};
Aw = {{-1, 2}, {0, -4}};
mat := {{x1[t]*x2[t]^2, 37}, {x1[t]*Cos[x2[t]], 2}}; (*** No Inverse[] ***)
eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};

eqdyn = D[ser[t], t] == Aw . ser[t];
eqinn = ser[0] == {1, 1};

ev = WhenEvent[
      Mod[t, 1], {#1 -> LinearSolve[#2, #1], "RestartIntegration"}
      ] &[ser[t], mat];

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqinn, ev}, ser[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
ev
(*
WhenEvent[
 Mod[t, 1], {{x1[t], x2[t]} -> 
   LinearSolve[{{x1[t] x2[t]^2, 37}, {Cos[x2[t]] x1[t], 2}}, {x1[t], 
     x2[t]}], "RestartIntegration"}]
*)
```

Comment: really thanks for showing me the LinearSolve command, I'm gonna try to see if I'm do use it on my original code !

Comment: Nice code (+1).  I think that your code could be effective in a case of large matrix. Only you need to replace `LinearSolve` with `PseudoInverse` in a case of singular matrix.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks. I'd suggest `LeastSquares`, which is to `PseudoInverse` as `LinearSolve` is to `Inverse`.